# Discord bot functions differently on ios versus android and desktop

Tags: android, ios, node.js, discord.js

I have a bot that works flawlessly on desktop's app for Discord and Discord on my personal Android phone/mobile... but the same exact steps done on an IPhone/IOS does not work. I have little to no background on how IOS differs from Android or Windows as I have never owned Apple products...

Primarily, this has to do with when a query has escaped values. Someone enters a value (card name for a TCG bot I'm making) like "Drago's Fury". The ' gets escaped on desktop and android and the card title is put in double quotes versus being left in single quotes on the IOS version. Because of this, when that card's name is compared to a master list of cards, it cannot be found.

Here is how I get the master list that all card names get matched to via a loop...

```
 var sql = `SELECT * FROM ??`
  var inserts = ['cardsmaster']
  con.query(sql, inserts, (error, rows, fields) => { 

  let cardsList = []
  for (var i in rows) {
       cardsList.push(rows[i].name)
  }
```

The following code is run when a user is asked what cards to add. The reply is taken and run through a loop to match to the master list...

```
async function addToDeckQuestion(){

     const agree = "✅"
     const disagree = "❌"
     let msg = await message.author.send(`Would you like to add cards to ${userdeckname}? Please react with one of the following...`)
     await msg.react(agree)
     await msg.react(disagree)

     const filter = (reaction, user) => {
      return ['✅', '❌'].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && user.id === message.author.id;
      };

     const reply = await msg.awaitReactions(filter, { max: 1 })
     .catch(console.error);

     const addtodeck = reply.first()
     return addtodeck
     }

     let addtodeck = await addToDeckQuestion();

     if (addtodeck.emoji.name == agree){

     message.author.send("You have agreed to add cards to this new deck.")

     async function cardExists() {

     let msg = await message.author.send(`Please provide the cardnames that you would like to add to '${userdeckname}'.\n\n**NOTE:** Please separate each card with a comma and space, like so "Pact of Darkness, Aquos Slam, Karmic Balance"`)

       const filter = m => m.author.id === message.author.id
       const reply = await msg.channel.awaitMessages(filter, { max: 1 })
       .catch(console.error);

       let cardsToAdd = await reply.first()

       let usercardnamearray = await cardsToAdd.content.split(", ")

       let matchedcards = []
       let unmatchedcards = []

       for (let i = 0; i < usercardnamearray.length; i++) {

       usercardnamearray[i] = usercardnamearray[i].replace(/'/gi, "\'"); 

       let found = cardsList.indexOf(`${usercardnamearray[i]}`)
       console.log(found)

       if (found >= 0) {                                             
matchedcards.push(usercardnamearray[i])
     } else if (found == -1){
unmatchedcards.push(usercardnamearray[i])
     }     
  }
   console.log('Finished!')
   return await [matchedcards, unmatchedcards]
}

let cards = await cardExists();  

let matchedcards = await cards[0]      
let unmatchedcards = await cards[1]


if (unmatchedcards.length >= 1){ 

message.author.send(await `The card **${unmatchedcards.join(", ")}** could **NOT** be added. Please check your spelling, capitalization and enter just these card names again!`)
 }
```

So, for example, a user on desktop of Android would follow the step depicted in this image [image: here]

The below images are from console logging the "found" variable in the code above.

This is how the command is console logged on Desktop and Android:
[image: here]

And this is how the command is console logged on IOS:
[image: here]

I would expect both versions to react to javascript the same way, but something about this doesn't work with IOS nicely. The only difference I have noticed is that Drago's Fury gets put in double quotes in desktop and Android, but not on IOS. I am unsure how to go about fixing this so my IOS users aren't excluded from using the bot entirely.

Any ideas as to why the same info gets interpreted differently in IOS than just about anything else? Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since iOS 11, single and double quotation marks are made into their curly alternatives by default. For example, the default ASCII single quote character `'` is typed as `‘` or `’` depending on the placement. However, users can turn this off in Settings, so it isn't consistent among all Apple users.

What this means for your code is that the search string is using a different character for the apostrophe in `Drago's Fury`. Therefore, the search isn't coming back with it because the two characters are actually different.

A simple solution is to replace these characters with the default ASCII characters used in the names.

```js
const str = 'Drago’s Fury';
console.log(str);

const corrected = str.replace(/‘|’/g, '\'');
console.log(corrected);
```

Comment: And putting in that replace line wouldn't affect how android and Windows interpret things as well, I am assuming. IOS needs to be so complicated, doesn't it? lol I'll try putting the line in and see how testing goes.

Comment: Anywhere where the curly single quotes are used, they'll be interpreted as the default ASCII single quote character. Generally speaking it would only affect iOS users, but you actually could type the alternatives on Windows and Android.

Comment: I added in this line `usercardnamearray[i] = usercardnamearray[i].replace(/‘|’/gi, '\'');` right below the other replace line I have in the code I posted above and it didn't seem to fix anything. Maybe I am putting it in the wrong place or doing something wrong? I tried it with gi and just g as well, no dice.

Comment: Can you log `usercardnamearray[i]` before and after this replacement?

Comment: I figured out I was putting it in the wrong part of my code than what was being run when I tested it. Worked perfectly once I put it in the right spot! Thanks for your continued help with my problems.